# Bootstrap Panel Content not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I use bootstrap 2.3 But I need some bootstrap panels from bootstrap 3. Then I use that panel CSS part but that Panel content also goes inside panel title.

Here you can see original Panel [CLICK HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)

I got some CSS parts from it. But it's unsuccessful. Here I create a Fiddle
here I paste some codes also

```
.panel-primary {
    border-color: #428BCA;
}

.panel {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
   /*border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
    background-color: #428BCA;
    border-color: #428BCA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.panel-heading {
    /*/border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-title {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.panel-body:before, .panel-body:after
{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.panel-body:after
{
clear: both;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6XKdX/)

Comment: Why do you even do this? Why combine both? Why don't you just use bootstrap 3?

Comment: No.i use template.it already used 2.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your main issue is that you never closed the `panel-heading` div

You have:

```
<div id="box1" class="span4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
         <div> <!-- Forgot to close off div -->
         <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
    </div>
</div>
       </div>
```

What you should have instead:

```
<div id="box1" class="span4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <div class="panel-heading">
               <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore I created a customized version of Bootstrap 3 that only has the CSS for the panel. Paste it in to your CSS and you should be good to go.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*! normalize.css v3.0.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}
a {
  background: transparent;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
img {
  border: 0;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}
hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  overflow: visible;
}
button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input {
  line-height: normal;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}
optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
a {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #2a6496;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-rounded {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.img-thumbnail {
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel-heading > .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  color: inherit;
}
.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
}
.panel-title > a {
  color: inherit;
}
.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.panel > .list-group .list-group-item {
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.panel > .list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel-heading + .list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.panel > .table,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.panel > .table:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > thead:first-child > tr:first-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .table:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child td:first-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child th:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child td:last-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tbody:last-child > tr:last-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child > tfoot:last-child > tr:last-child th:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
.panel > .panel-body + .table,
.panel > .panel-body + .table-responsive {
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.panel > .table > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th,
.panel > .table > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.panel > .table-bordered,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
  border: 0;
}
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr:first-child > td,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr:first-child > td,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:first-child > td,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:first-child > td,
.panel > .table-bordered > thead > tr:first-child > th,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr:first-child > th,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:first-child > th,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td,
.panel > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
.panel > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.panel > .table-responsive {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.panel-group .panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel-group .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.panel-group .panel-footer {
  border-top: 0;
}
.panel-group .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.panel-default {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #dddddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #dddddd;
}
.panel-primary {
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-primary > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-primary > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #428bca;
}
.panel-success {
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-success > .panel-heading {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-success > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-success > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel-info {
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-heading {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-warning {
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-warning > .panel-heading {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-warning > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-warning > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #faebcc;
}
.panel-danger {
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.panel-danger > .panel-heading {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.panel-danger > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #ebccd1;
}
.panel-danger > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #ebccd1;
}
```